# Dense and Sparse Tensor Input to TensorFlow Model in Java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

After training the model in python & loading it in Java, for making predictions, how is it possible to create sparse tensors for categorical inputs.

I could successfully create tensors for numeric values as :

```
   Tensor x =
        Tensor.create(
            new long[] {2, 4},
            FloatBuffer.wrap(
                new float[] {
                  6.4f, 3.2f, 4.5f, 1.5f,
                  5.8f, 3.1f, 5.0f, 1.7f
                }));
```

**But for Categorical data, we need Sparse Tensors, how can we create it?**

Please find my input_fn() as :

```
def input_fn(df):
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
  # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                     for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}

  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
  categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                      for k in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS}

  # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols.items() + categorical_cols.items())

  # Converts the label column into a constant Tensor.
  label = tf.constant(df[LABEL_COLUMN].values)

  # Returns the feature columns and the label.
  return feature_cols, label
```

So what if i have input like below:

```
age   workclass fnlwgt  education education_num  marital_status occupation      race   LABEL(Income_bracket)
39   State-gov  77516    Bachelors  13          Never-married    Adm-clerical    White    3
```

**How can i create a tensor for continous values and categorical values and merge them to be provided as the input to Tensorflow in JAVA.**

Find the code for training the model in python - https://gist.github.com/gaganmalhotra/cd6a5898b9caf9005a05c8831a9b9153

@ash